# Javassist: Modify existing object instance through byte-code injection

Tags: java, bytecode

I am a recent entrant to `Javassist` and desire to capture `this` object within a method, add a new method to `this` class and execute new byte-code against an instance of `this`.

I begin with a simple `Test` class

```
public class Test
{

   public String eventId;


public String getEventId()
{
    DynamicBehaviorControl.executeBehaviorForEventTest("{ eventId = \"163\"; }", "Test", this);

    return eventId;
}
```

}

I am attempting to modify `this` as `Test test = new Test()` in which `test` is executing `getEventId() DynamicBehaviorControl.executeBehaviorForEventTest("{ eventId = \"163\"; }", "Test", this);` whereby the definition of `executeBehaviorForEventTest` is

```
public static void executeBehaviorForEventTest(String behavior, String classname, Object object)
{
    dynamicBehaviorModification(behavior, classname, object);
}
```

and `dynamicBehaviorModification` is

```
 protected static void dynamicBehaviorModification(String methodBehavior, String className, Object otherobject) {

    classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    classLoader = new Loader(classPool);


    try 
    {   
        //compileTimeClass = classPool.makeClass(className);

        compileTimeClass = classPool.get(className);

        compileTimeMethod = CtNewMethod.make("public void executeOnBehalfOfEvents()" + methodBehavior, compileTimeClass);

        //compileTimeMethod = compileTimeClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

        //compileTimeMethod.setBody(methodBehavior);

        compileTimeClass.addMethod(compileTimeMethod);

        compileTimeClass.writeFile();

        //classLoader.loadClass(className);

        //compileTimeClass = classPool.get(className);

        Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);

        //Object anotherObject = clazz.newInstance();

        Object object = clazz.newInstance();

        method = otherobject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

        method.invoke(otherobject, new Object[]{});

        purgeAndKill();

    } 
    catch (CannotCompileException cannotCompileException)
    {
        logger.debug(cannotCompileException.getMessage() + " | " + cannotCompileException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "ctMethod.setBody(\"{\" + behavior +  \"}\"); or ctClass.toClass();");
    } 
    catch (SecurityException securityException) 
    {
        logger.debug(securityException.getMessage() + " | " + securityException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, null);");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchMethodException noSuchMethodException)
    {
        logger.debug(noSuchMethodException.getMessage() + " | " + noSuchMethodException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, null);");
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) 
    {
        logger.debug(illegalArgumentException.getMessage() + " | " + illegalArgumentException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "method.invoke(invocationObject);");
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException illegalAccessException)
    {
        logger.debug(illegalAccessException.getMessage() + " | " + illegalAccessException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "method.invoke(invocationObject);");
    } 
    catch (InvocationTargetException illegalInvocationTargetException) 
    {
        logger.debug(illegalInvocationTargetException.getMessage() + " | " + illegalInvocationTargetException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "method.invoke(invocationObject);");
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException instantiationException) 
    {
        logger.debug(instantiationException.getMessage() + " | " + instantiationException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "Object object = clazz.newInstance();");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) 
    {
        logger.debug(classNotFoundException.getMessage() + " | " + classNotFoundException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "classLoader.loadClass(className);");
    } 
    catch (NotFoundException notfoundException) 
    {
        logger.debug(notfoundException.getMessage() + " | " + notfoundException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "Object object = clazz.newInstance();");
    }catch (IOException ioException) {
        logger.debug(ioException.getMessage() + " | " + ioException .getCause() + " | " + 
                "compileTimeClass.writeFile();");
    }

}
```

I assume one object can modify the instance of another providing `this` object is obtained.  The part I don't understand is how to get `this` and then inject the new `bytecode` so `method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);` doesn't return a `NoMethodDefinedException`.

Comment: I determined I'm not writing the new class file with the modified byte code over the original.  Doing this enables the `this` object to execute new behavior on its' instance.  I do have another puzzling question regarding class loading.  I am using the `JavaAssist` class loader in addition to the `Java` class loader as such `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
   
compileTimeClass = classPool.get(className);` but is it necessary to use both to ensure `this` executes the updated class?

Comment: There is no relationship between the new class you are creating and the class of that existing object. What you are trying to do, is simply impossible.

Comment: @Holger I'm not creating a new class but obtaining an existing class whose `this` is known and I need to change an instance of `this` using the class in which `dynamicBehaviorModification` exists.  I understand I wasn't overwriting the class file I wanted to change with the injected byte code.  I'm trying to discover if I can inject byte code without having to write it using `CtClass.write()`

Comment: As already said, *you are not injecting byte code*. You are creating a new, entirely unrelated class, which happens to have identical properties, like the same name, which is irrelevant to the JVM, as classes are identified by their combination of defining class loader and name. Two classes with the same name but different loaders are still different classes. You used the old class as a template for the new class, but that doesn’t change the old class. It doesn’t work that way, whether you use `CtClass.write()` or not.